# Eway Transparent Redirect issue

Tags: payment-gateway

I have integrated eway Transparent Redirect which allow to take payment on site it self, it was working great but now it redirect user to eway hosted page and ask for password. see attached image.

As per this url, payment will be done in site and user don't need to leave site.
https://www.eway.com.au/developers/api/transparent-redirect

Is there any way to avoid that page?
here is simple demo I have created,
http://project-demo-server.info/eway/transparentredirect/

[image: Password page where eway redirect me]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've enabled [3D Secure](http://go.eway.io/s/article/What-is-3D-secure) on your eWAY Sandbox account. This adds a page in the transaction flow which mimics the bank's 3D Secure process.

You can disable it by:

1. Logging in to your Sandbox account
2. Go to **Settings** > **Sandbox**
3. Under "Customise Sandbox Behaviour" untick the box labelled "3-D Secure"

[image]